# I'm not light if you turn me around

Tags: riddle

> I am very heavy, but if you turn me around, then I am not.

**Hints:**

> I'm not light if you turn me around.

If you still can't solve it, then here's another hint:

> Add quotation marks to 'not'

Comment: Just as @MariiaMykhailova said, you should not put hints too early as there are users from different time zones who haven't taken a look at your question yet. Hints are usually given after a while (e.g. a few hours or a day maybe) so I think that is what you should do :D

Comment: Your riddles are very short and sweet. I love it :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The hint seems to be a little too early? :-)

> I'm a ton