# A quick and easy riddle

Tags: riddle

Here's a short riddle that my cousin told me:

> Forwards I am heavy, backwards I am not.
>
> What am I?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm not light if you turn me around](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71680/im-not-light-if-you-turn-me-around) (Was reading this one just today after some click-throughs from a meta post!)

Comment: Ah, missed the repost. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's

> ton

Because

> weighs a lot

and

> is literally "not" backwards